# Set ComboBox datasource in parent Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, combobox, datasource, parent

I am loading personnel data from database and fill a dataset as follows:

```
sql = " select * from personnel "
daAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn)
daAdapter.Fill(dsDataset, "personnel ")
dgvPersonnel.datasource=dsDataset.Tables("personnel ")

sql = " select depId, name from department "
daAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn)
daAdapter.Fill(dsDataset, "department")

'Set department combobox datasource for filtering
cmbDepartment.DataSource = dsDataset.Tables("department")
cmbDepartment.DisplayMember = "name"
cmbDepartment.ValueMember = "depId"

'Set datasource for personnel datagridview
dgvPersonnel.datasource=dsDataset.Tables("department")
```

Now when I double click any personnel in the dgvPersonnel I load an other form "frmPersonnelDatails" to be able to modify personnel data where I also have a combobox to select the department of the personnel.

My Concern now is how can I set the datasource of the combobox in the "frmPersonnelDatails" form to be the department table in my dataset instead of querying the database again to load then. Meaning I do not want to query the data more than one time. I tried the following but could not get the results:

```
Try
    serviceNo= dgvPersonnel.Rows(dgvPersonnel.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value
    Dim form As New frmPersonnelDatails
    personnelMode = "modify"

    form.cmbDepartment.DataSource = dsDataset.Tables("department")
    form.cmbDepartment.DisplayMember = "name"
    form.cmbDepartment.ValueMember = "depId"

    form.ShowDialog()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(Err.Description)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the datasource of the combobox in your other form send this `DataSet` in your constructor...

Here's an example:

```
 Dim fPD As frmPersonnelDatails = New frmPersonnelDatails('YOUR DS') 'Pass your dataset in the constructor'
 fPD.ShowDialog()
```

In your class: frmPersonnelDatails make sure there's a new constructor...

```
 Sub New(ByVal dSet As DataSet)
    cmbDepartment.DataSource = dSet.Tables("department")
    cmbDepartment.DisplayMember = "name"
    cmbDepartment.ValueMember = "depId"
 End Sub
```

Another option is to declare a new DataSet in your class as so and then set this on the new....

```
 Private datSet As DataSet
```

Then in your new sub.... you can set it...

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal dSet As DataSet)
    datSet = dSet 'Now you have your DataSet and you can use it anywhere you want'
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. CoDeXeR, I have got it working perfectly. Well, I added one more code line to your first answer which is: InitializeComponent()

Comment: Right, this was from memory... If this helped don't forget to upvote. Thanks!